# Eclipse new child option only available for containment equals true

Tags: eclipse, new-operator, instance

I have a ecore metamodel which have some relationships between its classes. Some of them are containments while others not. I have created a dynamic instance that I edit with the sample reflective editor.

At this point, I can't create childs from classes with a relationship different from a containment. This is, the "new child" option is not available in the menu, only "new sibling".

I don't understand why. I don't want to tweak the metamodel adding containers in all the relationships as the metamodel is correct without containments. And only setting containment/container to true enables the new child option in the dynamic instance.

How to proceed? Why this limitation?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Since your non-containment relationships are not contained, you cannot create a new instance via "new child". Instead you can only reference an existing object.

More precisely: let's assume your EClass A has a non-containment reference named "ref" to EClass B. If you create an instance of A and select it in the editor, you will find a property "ref" in the properties view where you can select instances of B.

Note that you have to create instances of B in their own EResource (i.e. file). To be able to reference them from the instance of A, you have to load the resource containing the instance of B.

Comment: Dear Tillmann, thank you for your answer. Do I need to create a file EResource for just a relationship between two classes at the model level? I mean, I want to instantiate my metamodel with instances. At the metamodel level, there is a simple relationship (association) between 2 metaclasses. At the model level, the instances will be associated as well. Do I need to create a EResource file for each associated class? If yes, how? Thanks again for your answer. Best regards.

Comment: And a final question, do you know if there is an UML editor for eclipse to graphically create metamodels and models based on xmi? It will be easier than editing the xmi file with the sample reflective editor. Thank you very much for your answers Tillman. Best regards, Dconversor.

Comment: Hi Dconversor, each model element is bound to an EResource. If your model element is not contained by any other model element, you need to put it in its own EResource (as root element). To create a new EResource, you can either use the reflective editor (i.e. call _Create Dynamic Instance_ on the EClass you want to instantiate) or the generated new wizard (which allows to choose the EClass of the root element). There is a graphical Ecore editor in the [Ecore Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/?project=ecoretools) of EMFT. I've never used it, but you might have a look at it.